# R, ggplot2, could not find function "ggplotify"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a treemap. I have installed all the necessary packages:

> install.packages("ggplot2")
>
> install.packages("reshape2")
>
> install.packages("plyr")
>
> install.packages("devtools")

I am running the first part of my code fine:

```
 library(treemapify)
 library(devtools)
 treeMapCoordinates <- treemapify(df,
                             area = "MMR_Count",
                             fill = "MMR_Count",
                             label = "Business",
                             group = "Year")
```

here is where the error occurs:

```
treeMapPlot <- ggplotify(treeMapCoordinates)
```

This is the error message:

> Error in ggplotify(treeMapCoordinates) : 
>        could not find function "ggplotify"

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Search google, the first result you get is the documentation for `ggplotify` which shows it is a function from the package `treemapify`. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/treemapify/versions/0.2.2/topics/ggplotify

Comment: @JackBrookes I have installed Treemapify, that is the question why it is not calling

Comment: https://github.com/wilkox/treemapify/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ggplotify&type= , so try using `geom_treemap`

Comment: @user20650 yes, treemapify is depricated and geom_treemap is the new function, I got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    ggplot2::ggplot(treeMapCoordinates, ggplot2::aes(area = MMR_Count, fill = MMR_Count)) 
+ geom_treemap()
```

could this work? Its basically an example of 
geom_treemap function documentation with your "area" and "fill" name.

P.S. ggplotify doesn't work for me too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not test it, but @user20650 answered it correctly